# Django model formset : customize empty form fields

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, formset

If I have a view that shows a formset of users for administration purpose (easy CRUD approach for admin like *admin page*).

I want the instance forms to show normal data like '`username`', '`first_name`', '`last_name`', '`email`', but in empty form (adding new user) I want to add extra field for '`password`'.

To be precise, in formset model table view, the admin can give password to new user but can't change or view password of existing user.

how to achieve that ?

I've tried to split fields in forms like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Form

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        # change to user data only fields
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name', 'email']  

class UserControlForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        # add user permissions fields
        fields = ['password','groups','is_active', 'is_superuser']
```

but still can't figure out how to apply the approach within formset table view

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @shawnngtq changed my process flow design :')